# How to get hidden field value when check box is checked in a repeater controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have asp.net repeater controller and I am trying to get the value of a hidden field when `CheckBox1_CheckedChanged`

```
<ul id="sortable">
    <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rep_sortable">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <li class="ui-state-default">
               <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>
               <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Body") %> 
               <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Completed") %> 
               <asp:CheckBox ID="chb_com"  runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" Checked='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Completed")  %>' oncheckedchanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged"/>
               <asp:HiddenField ID="hf_reminderID" runat="server" Value='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ReminderID")  %>'/>
            </li>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</ul>
```

c#

```
protected void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   foreach()
}
```

Comment: Look up the itemcommand method of the repeater control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [NamingContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.namingcontainer.aspx) to find sibling controls.

```
protected void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var checkBox = (CheckBox) sender;
    var reminderHiddenField = (HiddenField)checkBox.NamingContainer
        .FindControl("hf_reminderID");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code should work:

```
protected void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var checkBox = sender as CheckBox;
            var hiddenField = checkBox.Parent.FindControl("hf_reminderID") as HiddenField;
            var value = hiddenField.Value;
        }
```